# Sourcing _vimrc causes strange highlight issues

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using GVim for Windows and I've been playing around a lot with my _vimrc, installing plugins and whatnot and I keep running into a strange highlight error.  It's nothing that's causing major functional issues, it's just incredibly annoying.  So every time I make a change to my _vimrc, I've been sourcing it with `:so %` or `:so ~/_vimrc`, and immediately after I source it, all apostraphes and quotation marks are highlighted.  The only way to get rid of it is to close gVim completely and re-open it.

Now, this problem *only* occurs when I source the file within gVim.  It doesn't happen when I just open gVim normally.  Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?  I've included screenshots below to show what is happening.

Additionally, I have tried individually disabling all my plugins and testing it and it doesn't seem to be caused by a plugin.

Before sourcing _vimrc:
[image: Before Sourcing]

After sourcing _vimrc:
[image: After sourcing]

Comment: Does `nohl` remove the highlighting?

Comment: Yep that did it.  Will I just have to do that every time I source it or is there something I can do in my _vimrc?

Comment: Nohl simply hides the latest search (or whatever caused the highlighting). You can try putting nohl at the bottom of your vimrc or finding the source of the highlighting. There might be a typo somewhere that makes something search for those characters.

Comment: Or maybe its a side-effect of an intentional search and replace etc., in that case just put nohl at the bottom like I said.

Comment: Please include a textual version of your vimrc as well so we can try to reproduce it and find root cause.

Comment: @merlin2011 http://pastebin.com/V9DJwGHs

Comment: @DarthCthulhu, Given the number of plugins that you have, my best guess is that at least one of them is not idempotent.